# Icons on the UIAlert Controller

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller

Does anyone know how to add icons in the UI Alert Controller the way the Pages App has it as attached i the image below.

Thanks in advance. :)

[image]

Comment: This is not simple `UIAlerController`, this a `UIDocumentMenuViewController`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes that is possible. You can try to set image property 0f action. You should probably try out following code

```
var okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .Default, handler: nil)
let img = UIImage(named: "ico_ok.png")
action.setValue(img, forKey: "image")
alert.addAction(action)
```

Comment: Note that this isn't documented or supported. Use at your own risk.

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thanks. ;)